# Random img location add & remove loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add an image to a div and assign its location inside the div randomly by setting "left" & "top" css rules.

I then want the image to fade in display for a sort period of time before fading away and looping through to show one at another location.

```
<div id="banner">
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/BqsAMv7.png" alt="pin drop" class="pin"/>
</div>

(function randomPin(){  
var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();

$pin.css({
    'position':'absolute',
    'left':posx+'px',
    'top':posy+'px',
    'display':'none'
}).appendTo( '#banner' ).fadeIn(500).delay(500).fadeOut(300, function(){
    $(this).remove();
}); 
})();
```

DEMO - [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QcUPk/2555/)

Comment: the size of the image (from an old attempt), I guess that changes to 39px & 52px

Comment: And where you define it?

Comment: Your taking the width and height off of the position to consider the size of the image so I guess it would be something like - 
($(document).width() - 39px)).toFixed();

Comment: That would place the pin in the same place every time ?

Comment: You're complicating it -> **http://jsfiddle.net/QcUPk/2558/**

Comment: @adeneo very nice but sometimes go out of the container ;)

Comment: Oo I see what you did there it does sometimes go out so maybe display:none; if pin isnt inside the banner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't define `divsize` and `$pin`. Futhermore there is no function which you can call every time the pin should placed at a random position.

The suggest the following code:

```js
(function randomPin(){
    var $pin = $('.pin');
    var $banner = $('#banner');
    var divsize = [$banner.width() - $pin.width(), $banner.height() - $pin.height()];
    
    function show() {
        var posx = (Math.random() * (divsize[0])).toFixed();
        var posy = (Math.random() * (divsize[1])).toFixed(); 
        
        $pin
            .css({
                'left':posx+'px',
                'top':posy+'px'
            })
            .fadeIn(500)
            .delay(500)
            .fadeOut(300, show); 
    }
    show();
    
})();
```

```css
#banner{
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.pin {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/BqsAMv7.png" alt="pin drop" class="pin"/>
</div>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QcUPk/2561/)